# Upper/lower bound on covariance two dependent random random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

X and Y are two dependent random variables. Marginal pmfs f(X) and f(Y) is given, but joint pmf f(X,Y) is not known. Is it possible to find upper/lower bound on covariance cov(X,Y)?

Answer (score 16):

The covariance between $X$ and $Y$ is defined as
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)={\rm E}[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)],
$$
where $\mu_X={\rm E}[X]$ and $\mu_Y={\rm E}[Y]$ are the two means. By Cauchy-Schwarz' inequality we have
$$
\begin{align}
|\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)|&=|{\rm E}[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)]|\leq {\rm E}\left[(X-\mu_X)^2\right]^{1/2}{\rm E}\left[(Y-\mu_Y)^2\right]^{1/2}\\
&=\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(X)\mathrm{Var}(Y)}.
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
\mathrm{Var}(X)\mathrm{Var}(Y)=\left\{\int (x-\mu_X)^2\, f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx\right\}\cdot\left\{\int (y-\mu_Y)^2f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy\right\}.
$$

Every value between the lower and upper bound can be realized. To see this let $X,X'$ be i.i.d. and $U$ a Bernoulli variable independent of $(X,X')$ with $P(U=1)=p$. If we let $Y=UX+(1-U)X'$, then
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(Y,X)=\mathrm{Cov}(UX,X)+\mathrm{Cov}((1-U)X',X)=\mathrm{Cov}(UX,X).
$$
By expanding this we obtain 
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(Y,X)=E[U]\mathrm{Var}(X)=p\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(X)\mathrm{Var}(Y)}
$$
since $X\sim Y$. Letting $p$ vary between $0$ and $1$ we can realize all values between $0$ and the upper bound $\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(X)\mathrm{Var}(Y)}$.

Finally, let $Y=-(UX+(1-U)X')$, then we still have $X\sim Y$, but now
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=-p\sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(X)\mathrm{Var}(Y)}.
$$

Comment: Maybe add an argument to show that every value in the interval your answer shows, can be realized.

Comment: Thanks Stefan. :) I think this will help me.

Comment: @did sorry u r right. since it is absolute it is between $-x$ and $x$.

Comment: @Did: I added an argument that shows that the end points can be realized. I'm not sure how to argue that everything in between can be realized without turning to a two-dimensional Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Try $Y=\pm (UX+(1-U)X')$ with $(X,X')$ i.i.d. and $U$ Bernoulli $0$ or $1$ independent (if $\pm=+$, $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed).

Comment: @Did: Thank you. And let me just say that I really appreciate your comments. It helps me improve as well.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. Said comments are formulated in this spirit.