# Covariance$(X,Y) \geq 0$ if $X,Y \geq 0$?

Tags: probability, correlation

I was wondering if you can say something about the covariance of two positive variables $X$ and $Y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot conclude that $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)\geq 0$ in general. To see this, let $X\sim\mathrm{bin}(1,p)$ and $Y=1-X$, then obviously $P(X\geq 0)=P(Y\geq 0)=1$ but
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathrm{Cov}(X,1-X)=-\mathrm{Cov}(X,X)=-\mathrm{Var}(X)<0
$$
if $p\in (0,1)$.

In general you have the bound (see e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348876/upper-lower-bound-on-covariance-two-dependent-random-random-variables/348891#348891)):
$$
|\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)|\leq \sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(X)\mathrm{Var}(Y)}
$$

Comment: I just wonder about the case when we consider the covariance as the multiplication of the square root of each variances, namely sigmas, by the correlation. Sigmas are positive definite and I assume that I have $X,Y>0$, then i just imagine realization of $X,Y$ and any shifted innerproduct will also be positive and finally the multiplication of two positive things is also positive. What is the mistake in this understanding?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying about shifted innerproducts. But the covariance is negative if and only if the correlation is negative. And that $X,Y>0$ is not enough ensure that $X$ and $Y$ are positively correlated. The example in my answer is a simple example showing that $X$ and $Y$ can in fact be perfectly negative correlated (yielding a correlation of $-1$).

Comment: yes I know. I dont object to ur solution. It is completely okay. Here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation , if $f$ and $g$ are positive then it seems like the the correlation is also positive.

Comment: But what's the connection between cross-correlation and usual correlation? To me it seems that the cross-correlation is the density of $X+Y$ given that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and has densities.

Comment: If we have finite number of samples from $X$ and $Y$ and if we apply usual correlation when the number of samples tends to infinity do we get cross correlation? I was thinking in this direction without knowing if it is correct at all)

Comment: The usual correlation is a theoretic quantity which you cannot calculate based on samples. But you calculate the sample-based correlation (Pearson correlation) then I believe this would converge to the correlation as the number of observations tends to infinity, and not the cross-correlation.

Answer (score 1):

Might be interesting and related to your question:

http://www.math.tu-dresden.de/sto/schmidt/dsvm/dsvm2003-4.pdf