Is there an inequality for l-2 norms?
Is the following inequality correct?
$$E(X^2Y^2) \leq E(X^2)E(Y^2)$$
If this inequality is not correct, can I add some constant so that the inequality holds up to a constant?

related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/353814

No, it's not correct. Suppose that $X=Y$ always, and $X$ is chosen from $\{0,1\}$, each with probability $1 \over 2$. Then $E(X^2 Y^2) = E(X^2) = E(Y^2) = {1 \over 2}$, but ${1 \over 2} > {1 \over 4}$.
