# Upper bound on the covariance of two gamma processes?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Given two binary [gamma processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_process), $X = \Gamma(t; \gamma_1, \lambda_1)$ and  $Y = \Gamma(t; \gamma_2, \lambda_2)$, what is their maximum covariance?  Applying [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348876/upper-lower-bound-on-covariance-two-dependent-random-random-variables), it would seem that it is the product of their standard deviations, but I'm not exactly sure how to derive the variance of the gamma process, as opposed to that of the gamma distribution whence it is derived.

Since in my research I am generating (binary) gamma processes from gamma distributions, I would like an answer I could apply to any two gamma distributions (determined by either their shape/scale or shape/rate parameters) and get maximum covariance.

*Edit*: Example: Using Matlab's `gamrnd` function, let the shape/scale parameters for one gamma distribution be 4, 1 and for the other be 2, 4.  Taking the cdf of a randomly generated sequence and discretizing, I can get two corresponding processes like this:

```
0001000101001000100000010001100001010000100100110010001001010000010001001...
0000000000000000010001000100000010001000000010000000100000000000011000100...
```

But the two processes could also be like this:

```
0001000101001000100000010001100001010000100100110010001001010000010001001...
0001000000000000000001000000100010000000100000000000010001000000011001000...
```

The first process is unchanged; the second has had the intervals permuted so that it correlates better with the first.  Crucially such a change does not affect the parameters of the underlying gamma distribution.  However, there is a limit on how similar the second process can be to the first, given these parameters.  That limit is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I assume you mean the product of their standard deviations, not of their variances.

Comment: For any two random variables, the covariance is at most the product of the standard deviations, and this maximum is attained exactly when the two random variables are almost surely equal.  So to get maximum covariance, just make your second process the same as the first.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes thank you, edited accordingly.

Comment: @RobertIsrael No, I don't get to choose the processes, they are generated from data.  No specific process is generated, but the distributions of shape and scale parameters determining the underlying gamma distributions are derived from data.

Comment: So what precisely is the question, then?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Given X and Y as stated in the question, what is the (maximum) covariance, as a function of $\gamma_1, \gamma_2, \lambda_1, \lambda_2$?  Or even better, what is it as a function of the shape/scale parameters of the underlying gamma distributions.

Comment: What is the covariance of two random processes? The covariance of two random variables is clear, the auto-covariance of a random process is clear, but the covariance of two random processes?

Comment: This seems like an interesting question. Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$ whose distributions (cdf's) are known but whose *joint* distribution is unknown, what is their maximum correlation (equivalently, covariance)? A  correlation of $\pm 1$ can only be achieved if $X$ and $Y$ can be linearly related, which represents a very strong constraint relating their cdfs.

Comment: @Did I may not be using terminology in the right way, my background in probability theory is weak.  But I've added an example of what I'm talking about which I hope should make things clear.